# Targeting WP7 async powered projects in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, async-await, async-ctp

Is it possible to use async stuff in Windows Phone 8.0 SDK (Visual Studio 2012) and still targeting Windows Phone 7.1?

I installed Windows Phone 8.0 SDK and opened my WP7.1 project with references to AsyncCTP nuget package. The following compilation error occurs:

> Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?

I do not want to drop support of WP7.1, so upgrade to WP8 is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible using the latest version of the async CTP. You can find it on NuGet at [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

More information on the BCL Team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Note: The installation of this NuGet package seems a bit random. I had to try twice to make it work.